# J2ME IOError in socket::open = 11004

Tags: java, sockets, java-me

I am developing a small J2ME app for an assignment, and whenever I try to connect to any website, I get `IOError in socket::open = 11004`.

The sample code:

```
/* I am using a local XML server, but the error I get is similar to when
connecting to the url below. */
conn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml");

if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) { // The error is here
  // Some code
}
```

Edit: I am using Oracle emulator for this.

Answer (score 0):

does oracle emulator means Java ME platform SDK? i use the 3.0 and your code works like charm on it

try to add the following permission to the Application Descriptor - JAD file:

javax.microedition.io.Connector.http

read more on http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/package-summary.html in the Security of Networking Functions section